How set the body of request with QNetworkRequest
I currently post to a ReST server in Qt6 like this:
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl("someurl"));
QUrlQuery postData;
postData.addQueryItem("somekey","somevalue");
nm = new QNetworkAccessManager
reply = nm->post(request,postData.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());

However, I am told that I need to send some JSON in the body of the request.   Where do I set the body of the post?  The second parameter of the ->post method is the query parameters.
I'm guessing I need to combine the body (json document) with the postData but I'm not sure how.

Maybe using the post() variant that accepts QHttpMultiPart objects?

This is incorrect:

The second parameter of the ->post method is the query parameters.

The second parameter using this variant is to send the body, you have to place the QUrlQuery in QUrl.
QUrl url("someurl");

QUrlQuery query;
query.addQueryItem("somekey", "somevalue")
url.setQuery(query);
qDebug() << url;

QNetworkRequest request;
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
request.setUrl(QUrl);

QJsonObject obj;
obj["key1"] = "value1";
obj["key2"] = "value2";
QJsonDocument doc(obj);
QByteArray data = doc.toJson();
qDebug() << data;

nm = new QNetworkAccessManager();
reply = nm->post(request, data);

